# Free DDNS when ISP put you on CGN, I need to be able to use all the ports on my own server setup

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, administrator, ddns

My ISP has put me on CGN, the noip DDNS is not working, I have tried the ngrok too but it only gives me 1 free host and also it only open for a particular port.

I want to access my server over Internet, also there will be some apps which will be running on some specific port numbers so I want all port number to be accessed, and it should be free also if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngrok is a limited form of tunneling, and tunneling is the only way to accomplish what you're looking for. With any sort of NAT, your network is not reachable from the Internet without forwarding rules in the router. With CGN you don't even control the router, so there is no way to forward requests.

Basically, you do not have a real Internet connection, so it is not possible to use it like one.

Comment: So can I consult with my ISP to remove CGN and give me the controls over router? And how does tunneling works?

Comment: It very much depends on your ISP. If they even offer a service without CGN, it is almost certainly a higher priced "business class" service.

Comment: Okay, so what about tunneling and ngrok? Can we tweak them or can we achieve what ngrok is doing by implementing the same using different tools if possible?

Comment: The free version of ngrok supports up to four tunnels, which would equate to opening up four ports. I'm not aware of any free service that allows you to do more than that.

Comment: Another alternative would be for you to set up a VPN to a provider which will provide you with a static IP address, or roll your own (for example using a VM provider and OpenVPN).   Googling "VPN static IP provider" should produce some options of providers that will do this for you. If you want to do it for free, AWS gives you 1 years worth of a minimal EC2 instance you can run OpenVPN on, but that is going to require a lot more technical know-how.

Comment: What about IPv6? Can I get a free VPN with IPv6?

Comment: @davidgo https://freevpn.me/accounts/
 
Talking about VPNs I found https://freevpn.me/accounts/ this over the internet which seems to be free but I don't know how to use it to achieve what I want. Can any one explain me please?

Comment: Run a mile from this service.  First off, *it does not do what you need* (ie offer you an unique IP address you can reverse traffic through)  and second off the offering is dodgy.  (Support PPTP, Google tracking, no contact details,lies or at least deceptive representations on their site).